# Pattern in email body not exported in excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba, outlook, pattern-matching

I have a pattern in emails that i want to extract in a excel file.

The Serial Number XXXX0XX 0000000
(4 letters, 1 number,2 letters, 1 space, 7 numbers, 1 space)

Regex : \s*([0-9a-zA-Z]{7})\s*\w*\s*

The problem is that it doesn't gets the whole pattern, it takes just the last 7 digits.

```
Dim Reg1 As RegExp
Dim M1 As MatchCollection
Dim M As Match

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp

With Reg1
    .pattern = "The Serial Number+\s*([0-9a-zA-Z]){7}\s*\w*\s*" 
    .Global = True
End With
If Reg1.test(msg.Body) Then

    Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(msg.Body)
    For Each M In M1

        Set rng = wks.Cells(i, j)

        Dim strSubject As String
        Debug.Print M.SubMatches(1)
        strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
        rng.Value = strSubject
        j = j + 1


    Next
End If
```

Where rng.Value is the cell from excel.

Here is the entire code :

```
Sub SaveMessagesToExcel()


    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim strSheet As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim nms As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim fld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim nColonCharIndex As Integer
    Dim nBodyLength As Integer
    Dim nNewLineCharIndex As Integer
    Dim nOutputRow, nOutputColumn As Integer
    Dim itm As Object
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim strPrompt As String
    strTemplatesPath = "C:\serials\"
    strSheet = "not valid.xlsm"
    strSheet = strTemplatesPath & strSheet
    Debug.Print "Excel workbook: " & strSheet
    If TestFileExists(strSheet) = False Then
        strTitle = "Worksheet file not found"
        strPrompt = strSheet & _
        " not found; please copy Messages.xls to this folder and try again"
        MsgBox strPrompt, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, strTitle

    End If

    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strSheet)
    Set wkb = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    wks.Activate
    wks.Range("A2:C300").Cells.Clear
    Set nms = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Const FOLDER_PATH = "\\Mailbox - me\Inbox\serial"
    Set fld = OpenOutlookFolder(FOLDER_PATH)
    If fld Is Nothing Then

    End If


    If fld.DefaultItemType <> olMailItem Then
        MsgBox "Folder does not contain mail messages"

    End If

    lngCount = fld.Items.Count

    If lngCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No messages to export"

    Else
        Debug.Print lngCount & " messages to export"
    End If


    i = 3

    For Each itm In fld.Items
        If itm.Class = olMail Then

            Set msg = itm
            i = i + 1

            j = 1

            Set rng = wks.Cells(i, j)
            If InStr(1, msg.Body, "is not valid") Then rng.Value = msg.Subject
            j = j + 1

            Set rng = wks.Cells(i, j)
            If InStr(1, msg.Body, "is not valid") Then rng.Value = msg.ReceivedTime
            j = j + 1

    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match

        Set Reg1 = New RegExp

    With Reg1
        .pattern = "The Serial Number+([a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7})"  ' +\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*  [a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z ]{2}[0-9 ]{7}  \s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}\s*[0-9]{7}\s*
        .Global = True
    End With
    If Reg1.test(msg.Body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(msg.Body)


            Set rng = wks.Cells(i, j)

            Dim strSubject As String
            Debug.Print M.SubMatches(1)
            strSubject = M.SubMatches(1)
            rng.Value = strSubject
            j = j + 1

    End If
    End If
    Next itm


        wkb.Save
        wkb.Close
    MsgBox "DONE"

    appExcel.Application.Visible = True
    Set appExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strSheet)
    Set wkb = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    wks.Activate


End Sub
```

If i use +\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*)\s* it will write only the last 7 digits from the entire pattern. If i use ANYTHING else it just gives me object variable or with block variable not set (error 91) on line: Debug.Print M.SubMatches(1)

Comment: Try `The Serial Number\s*([0-9a-zA-Z]{7})\s*\w+` if you just need `XXXX0XX`. If you need `XXXX0XX 0000000`, use `The Serial Number\s*([0-9a-zA-Z]{7}\s*\w+)`

Comment: When in doubt, use an online regex debugger (e.g. https://regex101.com/) to see if your pattern does what you think it does.

Comment: @wittman: Instead of posting the entire code, you could just post the minimal complete verifiable example. What is the exact input and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your pattern, you quantified the *group* rather than the character class, so you only capture each `[0-9a-zA-Z]` 7 times and only the last captured letter/digit is stored in `Submatch(1)`. You need to put the limiting quantifier inside the group:

```
The Serial Number+\s*([0-9a-zA-Z]{7})\s*\w*\s*
                                 ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX2VOu/1)

Actually, `\s*\w*\s*` are not used in your current code and seem redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the link it is really helpful but the pattern didn't work

Comment: Why? What did you get and what did you expect to get?

Comment: Try [`The Serial Number\s+([a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2}\s+[0-9]{7})`](https://regex101.com/r/jX2VOu/3).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

if your pattern is 4 letters, 1 number, 1 space, 7 numbers, 1 space, then use the below line

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9 ]{1}[0-9 ]{7}
```

if your pattern is 4 letters, 1 number, 2 letters, 1 space, 7 numbers, 1 space, then use the below line

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z ]{2}[0-9 ]{7}
```